# how to establish connection between drupal and solr

Tags: ubuntu, connection, drupal, solr, web-crawler

I am working on technologies like drupal & solr.I have installed all required modules.but i need to know that how to crawl data from drupal.& how to form connector between drupal & solr.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned you've installed the required modules but ensure you've done the specifics required in the [Apache Solr readme](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/contributions/modules/apachesolr/README.txt?view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6--1):

- Get the Solr PHP client (around line 30 in the readme)
- Move schema.xml and solrconfig.xml from the drupal module directory to the relevant conf directory within your Solr install (around line 80)
- Browse to /admin/settings/apachesolr/settings and configure the solr host/port/path
- Check at /admin/settings/apachesolr/index and you should see items being indexed after cron runs
- There are then various options to filter content types, ignore or give weighting to specific content types etc